# Quick repair for cracked wallpapered ceiling

Tags: plaster

I'm decorating a room on a non existent budget and have a ceiling that has cracked plaster with wallpaper on it which has torn. I can't afford to have it replastered and don't have time to strip it etc. Therefore I wondered if anyone has any tips for covering up the cracked parts or fixing it somehow... Polyfilla over the top doesn't appear to have worked (see picture). I did consider cutting out the cracked paper area but am unsure if this will cause the plaster to fall off completely... Maybe tape would work?

See photos to see what I'm dealing with. Lighter is for scale!!

[image: Bad area]
[image: polyfilla attempted poor repair]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so in the end I cut away a small section of paper where the crack was to 'level' out the surface. I then just filled in the gap using polyfilla, sanded and painted - yes it doesn't look very good but it's a massive improvement on what was there.

I think the correct fix would be to cut away a larger section, use special tape to repair the crack and then paste new paper over the area - using a non uniform cut (zigzag/rough). At least that's what my old man told me!

Ultimately the best thing to do is replaster it.